# Flutter-Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, manifest

Here I am getting an error while run flutter project.

*** Error parsing LocalFile: 'D:\DEVELOPMENT\Paklayer\park_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' Please
ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again. ***

Here is my Manifest

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.park_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
   <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="park_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2"/>
    </application>
</manifest> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Add this line inside application tag : `<android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.park_app">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        
       <application
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            android:label="park_app"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                     the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                     while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                     to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                <meta-data
                  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                  android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
                <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                     Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                     screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                     gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                     Flutter's first frame. -->
                <meta-data
                  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                  android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Dont delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

For more info : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element